# Talend Send logs output via email

Tags: talend

I have a job in Talend and the part of getting the logs in the email are like this:

tLogCatcher --> main --> tJavaRow

```
I
```

onComponentOk --> tSendEmail

My point is that I want to send the output of the logs to an email to get notified.

I use in the tJavaRow:

```
globalMap.put("errorCode", input_row.message);
```

and in the tSendEmail:

```
"Hello, 
The input message is" +  (String)globalMap.get("errorCode")
```

However, the  (String)globalMap.get("errorCode") part always returns null, while the error message is different.

Do you have any idea why this is the case?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just connect `tLogCatcher` to `tSendMail` :

[image]

In tSendMail you can put this :

```
"Hello, The input message is" + ((String)globalMap.get("tLogCatcher_1_ERROR_MESSAGE"))
```

And obviously if there is no error or warning you will get `null`, so you need to add tWarn or tDie to your job, or just make it erroneous.